# How to make list of emits with intervals from Node.js to React using socket.io?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I need to make kind of «movie» (by «movie» I mean changing pages every N seconds) with JS.

I have array of objects coming from node.js and using socket.io I want to emit their content every N seconds to React.

Here is my API endpoint:

```
  router.get("/start/:handle", (req, res) => {
      Game
        .findOne({ url: req.params.handle })
        .then(game => {
          let questionList = [];
          game.blocks.map(block => {
            block.questions.map(question => {
              questionList.push(question)
            })
          })
          questionList.map(question => {
            return setInterval(
              res.status(200).send(question)
              , 5000);
          })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log("start game, err =>", err))
    })
```

But it doesn’t work. I have error

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function
```

Probably I need to do it somehow else. But I don’t have any idea how to make it.

Comment: You need to wrap `res.status(200).send(question)` in an anonymous function. (also, you don't need `map` here, or `return`. Just use `forEach`) That only fixes the current error though, sending multiple replies for a single request doesn't make any sense. If you want to update client-side content every N seconds, just use `setInterval` in the browser. No need for socket stuff.

Comment: @ChrisG I would also need to check time when I sent content to server/when I received reply from client. Also I want to avoid situation when client/server has some difference in time and push client from server. I.e. server sent content at 15:04:00, sever received it in 15:04:05 because of problems with internet, if N is 10 seconds, then I want to push client to change contebt after 10 seconds server time

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your interval logic in annynymous function as suggested by Chris.

Something like below should work.

```
var sendDataOnInterval = function (req, res) {
      // place all existing code
      res.send(question);
      sendDataOnInterval(recursive, 5000);
};

app.get('/start/:handle', sendDataOnInterval);
```